# How does the callback function work in multiprocessing map_async?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

It cost me a whole night to debug my code, and I finally found this tricky problem. Please take a look at the code below.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def myfunc(x):
    return [i for i in range(x)]

pool=Pool()

A=[]
r = pool.map_async(myfunc, (1,2), callback=A.extend)
r.wait()
```

I thought I would get `A=[0,0,1]`, but the output is `A=[[0],[0,1]]`. This does not make sense to me because if I have `A=[]`, `A.extend([0])` and `A.extend([0,1])` will give me `A=[0,0,1]`. Probably the callback works in a different way. So my question is how to get `A=[0,0,1]` instead of `[[0],[0,1]]`?

Comment: What operating system and python version are you using?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Callback is called once with the result (`[[0], [0, 1]]`) if you use map_async.

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>> def myfunc(x):
...     return [i for i in range(x)]
... 
>>> A = []
>>> def mycallback(x):
...     print('mycallback is called with {}'.format(x))
...     A.extend(x)
... 
>>> pool=Pool()
>>> r = pool.map_async(myfunc, (1,2), callback=mycallback)
>>> r.wait()
mycallback is called with [[0], [0, 1]]
>>> print(A)
[[0], [0, 1]]
```

Use [`apply_async`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) if you want callback to be called for each time.

```
pool=Pool()
results = []
for x in (1,2):
    r = pool.apply_async(myfunc, (x,), callback=mycallback)
    results.append(r)
for r in results:
    r.wait()
```

Comment: This code should not work, you need to put it under a `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, [(in Windows)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

Comment: Oh! Sorry then. You lucky mac/linux guys :P

Comment: @falsetru, it works. Thank you. Now I see a another difference between apply_async and map_async.

Comment: Using putting an `if __name__ == '__main__'` would make it work in Windows, as well as in other OSs, so I would suggest always doing it that way for improved portability.