# How to terminate a pool when any of the processes finishes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have used the following code as advised but still the pool is not terminated after first worker is finding a match. The desired result is to have 20 processes running function f and when any of them finds a match the pool should be terminated, what is happening instead is that I have to wait until all workers find a match.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np


def f(z):..Output omitted


class Worker():
    def __init__(self, workers):
        self.pool = Pool(processes=workers)

    def callback(self, result):
        if result:
            self.pool.terminate()

    def do_job(self):

        self.pool.map_async(f,range(1,20), callback=self.callback)
        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()


if __name__=="__main__":
    w = Worker(20)
    w.do_job()
```

Comment: probably you could use multiprocessing.Event, but I don't know how exactly to use it with map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Multiprocess Pool. How to exit the script when one of the worker process determines no more work needs to be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447055/python-multiprocess-pool-how-to-exit-the-script-when-one-of-the-worker-process)

Comment: Other possible duplicate: [How to get all pool.apply_async processes to stop once any one process has found a match in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691552/how-to-get-all-pool-apply-async-processes-to-stop-once-any-one-process-has-found/37700081#37700081)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I went over the links above but still I could not find a way to achieve my goal. I have tried to modify the code as above. Any idea?

Comment: What value does your `f` function return? Does it return the match when it finds it? Also, is it possible that your `f` function is returning a [falsy value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)  even if it finds a match?

Comment: The f function is running a while loop and it will not stop until it will hit True.

Comment: Ok but then does it return something or does it just stop?

Comment: Also it sounds like you want to use `apply_async` instead of `map_async`, see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19699363/5992438) for an explanation. `map_async` only calls the callback after every worker of the pool terminates

Comment: Hi, I have manage to solve the problem. I have called the w.callback(match) inside f so as soon as any process is finding a match in f the pool is terminated. Also I have replaced self.pool.map_async with self.pool.map and removed the self.pool.join(). Thank you!