# Running multiple python scripts from a single script, and communicating back and forth between them?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a script that I wrote that I am able to pass arguments to, and I want launch multiple simultaneous iterations (maybe 100+) with unique arguments. My plan was to write another python script which then launch these subscripts/processes, however to be effective, I need the that script to be able to monitor the subscripts for any errors.

Is there any straightforward way to do this, or a library that offers this functionality? I've been searching for a while and am not having good luck finding anything. Creating subprocesses and multiple threads seems straight forward enough but I can't really find any guides or tutorials on how to then communicate with those threads/subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to make use of threads. If you made the script you want to call into a function in this larger script, you could have your main function call this script as many times as you want and have the threads report back with information as needed. You can read a little bit about how threads work [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm).

Comment: Threads are limited by the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) though. For truly distributed processing you want some sort of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), perhaps even across the network.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) despite of requirements.

Simple way to communicate between Threads / Processes is to use [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). Multiprocessing module provides some other ways to communicate between processes (Queue, Event, Manager, ...)

You can see some elementary communication in the example:

```
import threading
from Queue import Queue
import random
import time


class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, queue_error):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.queue_error = queue_error

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 10))
        # Do some processing ...
        # Report errors
        self.queue_error.put((self.name, 'Error state'))


class Launcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue_error = Queue()

    def main_loop(self):
        # Start threads
        for i in range(10):
            w = Worker(i, self.queue_error)
            w.start()
        # Check for errors
        while True:
            while not self.queue_error.empty():
                error_data = self.queue_error.get()
                print 'Worker #%s reported error: %s' % (error_data[0], error_data[1])
            time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = Launcher()
    l.main_loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like someone else said, you have to use multiple processes for true parallelism instead of threads because the GIL limitation prevents threads from running concurrently.

If you want to use the standard *multiprocessing* library (which is based on launching multiple processes), I suggest using a [pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). If I understood correctly, you want to launch 100+ parallel instances. Launching 100+ processes on one host will generate too much overhead. Instead, create a pool of P workers where P is for example the number of cores in your machine and submit the 100+ jobs to the pool. This is simple to do and there are many [examples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) on the web. Also, when you submit jobs to the pool, you can provide a callback function to receive errors. This may be sufficient for your needs (there are examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699165/how-does-the-callback-function-work-in-python-multiprocessing-map-async)).

The Pool in multiprocessing however can't distribute work across multiple hosts (e.g. cluster of machines) last time I looked. So, if you need to do this, or if you need a more flexible communication scheme, like being able to send updates to the controlling process while the workers are running, my suggestion is to use [charm4py](https://github.com/UIUC-PPL/charm4py) (note that I am a charm4py developer so this is where I have experience).

With charm4py you could create N workers which are distributed among P processes by the runtime (works across multiple hosts), and the workers can communicate with the controller simply by doing remote method invocation. Here is a small example:

```
from charm4py import charm, Chare, Group, Array, ArrayMap, Reducer, threaded
import time

WORKER_ITERATIONS = 100


class Worker(Chare):

    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller

    @threaded
    def work(self, x, done_future):
        result = -1
        try:
            for i in range(WORKER_ITERATIONS):
                if i % 20 == 0:
                    # send status update to controller
                    self.controller.progressUpdate(self.thisIndex, i, ret=True).get()
                if i == 5 and self.thisIndex[0] % 2 == 0:
                    # trigger NameError on even-numbered workers
                    test[3] = 3
                time.sleep(0.01)
            result = x**2
        except Exception as e:
            # send error to controller
            self.controller.collectError(self.thisIndex, e)
        # send result to controller
        self.contribute(result, Reducer.gather, done_future)


# This custom map is used to prevent workers from being created on process 0
# (where the controller is). Not strictly needed, but allows more timely
# controller output
class WorkerMap(ArrayMap):
    def procNum(self, index):
        return (index[0] % (charm.numPes() - 1)) + 1


class Controller(Chare):

    def __init__(self, args):
        self.startTime = time.time()
        done_future = charm.createFuture()
        # create 12 workers, which are distributed by charm4py among processes
        workers = Array(Worker, 12, args=[self.thisProxy], map=Group(WorkerMap))
        # start work
        for i in range(12):
            workers[i].work(i, done_future)
        print('Results are', done_future.get())  # wait for result
        exit()

    def progressUpdate(self, worker_id, current_step):
        print(round(time.time() - self.startTime, 3), ': Worker', worker_id,
              'progress', current_step * 100 / WORKER_ITERATIONS, '%')
        # the controller can return a value here and the worker would receive it

    def collectError(self, worker_id, error):
        print(round(time.time() - self.startTime, 3), ': Got error', error,
              'from worker', worker_id)


charm.start(Controller)
```

In this example, the Controller will print status updates and errors as they happen. It
will print final results from all workers when they are all done. The result for workers
that have failed will be -1.

The number of processes P is given at launch. The runtime will distribute the N workers among the available processes. This happens when the workers are created and there is no dynamic load balancing in this particular example.

Also, note that in the charm4py model remote method invocation is asynchronous and returns a future which the caller can block on, but only the calling thread blocks (not the whole process).

Hope this helps.